# display number in a specific format in excel

Tags: c#, excel, styles, openxml

I am writing to excel using a list.Each row to be written to the excel will be stored as separate rows in the list.
The list contains numbers in specific format for certain columns.
Is there a way to identify the format of the number and apply cellStyle.Currently I am applying DataType as Number in case of numeric values.

```
if (Double.TryParse(value.Replace('.', ','), out output))
{
    value = value.Contains(',') ? value.Replace(",", "") : value;
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value.ToString());
    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

}
else
{
    cell.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
    cell.InlineString = new InlineString() { Text = new Text(outfile.DataRow[rowCnt].ToString()) };
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `value`? You seem to be calling `string` methods (like `Replace`) on it, but also `ToString`! Have you tried creating a spreadsheet that has the data and format you like using Excel and then using the Microsoft "OpenXML Productivity Tool" to crack it open and see the code that can create those data and formats. That's the easiest way to figure something like this out.